# How to pass char* to Python

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I need to pass two Python strings, representing an input file and an output file, to a C function named `decrypt_file`.

If I hardcode the string (for example, 'Test.OUT'), then it works.  I don't know how to use a variable string. The C function returns a string with wrong characters.

```c
int decrypt_file(char *inputfile, char *outputfile);
```

```py
try:
    file_name = bytes("example.txt", encoding='utf8')

    p_file_name = ctypes.create_string_buffer(file_name, len(file_name))
    so = "/home/hello/lib.so"
    sodium = ctypes.CDLL(so)
    sodium.strfry(p_file_name)
    sodium.decrypt_file.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_char_p]
    sodium.decrypt_file(p_file_name, ctypes.c_char_p(b"Test.OUT"))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

```
return ->  input file: mlxta.txeep
```

I use Linux and Pycharm terminal. Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Are the parameters both inputs-only, meaning `decrypt_file` doesn't write to the buffers?  Knowing what the function does changes how ctypes needs to be used.

Comment: I need a name for FILE * inpfile = fopen(inputfile, "rb"); and  FILE * outfile = fopen(outputfile, "wb"); . inputfile and outputfile are char * . Later I will write a file(outfile) with that name ( char * outputfile)

Comment: No need for `create_string_buffer` then and your `argtypes` above is correct.  Just pass the filenames as `bytes` objects.  FYI, `file_name = b'example.txt'` or `file_name = 'example.txt'.encode()` works as well as your `bytes('example.txt',encoding='utf-8')` example.  So `sodium.decrypt_file(b'input.txt',b'output.txt')` should work.  What do you mean by "The C function returns a string with wrong characters"?  Nothing is being returned here except an `int` return value.  Maybe you should show the C code if you have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ctypes was wrong. I don't know if this is the right way but it works.

```py
filename = b"helloworld.txt"
so = "/home/lib.so"
sodium = ctypes.CDLL(so)
sodium.decrypt_file.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char), ctypes.c_char_p]
sodium.decrypt_file(filename, ctypes.c_char_p(b"Test.OUT"))
```